# keep order of subselect

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query with a subselect that looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE x IN (SELECT a FROM table2 CONNECT BY PRIOR a=b START WITH b=0)
```

As I understand it, the subselect is ordered by hierarchy, but how can I give that order to the overall result?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you using.  This is far from standard SQL.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the results you want.

Comment: seems like It's `#Oracle`, isn't it ?

Comment: `IN` doesn't need an ordered input, it's satisfied as soon as it finds a match. There's no correlation between that subquery and the outer one.

Comment: yes its a oracle db

Comment: if you need to sort your final result from a column based on your sub query you have to use `join` instead